# Find element which contains text

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist me in following issue:
i have to pickup from dropdown elements which have **- Open** as a part of title (as per on screenshot below)
[image]

Since that **value** will be change during time period, it is useless to use that, and have to pickup ones with 'Open' status (not showed, but rest of statuses are: **Frozen** & **Closed**)
So, here is xpath which I tried:

```
//*[@id="period"]/contains(@text, '')
```

For above i got result from test  is **true**. (It does exist text as I understand that)
But when add wanted text

```
//*[@id="period"]/contains(@text, 'Open')
```

I got as a result **false** and can not find elements. 
Also, when searched with:

```
//*[@id="period"]
```

I got result (all periods are shown).

```
 01. Oct 2018 - 31. Oct 2018 - Open01. Sep 2018 - 30. Sep 2018 - Open01. Aug 2018 and so on ...
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<main class="main row">
<div class="content clearfix column medium-8">
<div class="row">
<article class="column medium-12">
<div class="t-box">
 <p></p><div class="compete">
 <a class="button primary" href="« Back to overview</a>
 <div class="promotion">
  <h2 class="promotion-header"><img src="/assets/images/system/stats/language/EN.png.pagespeed.ce.nTcGwJ7dzC.png">Top of the month</h2>
```

```
 <form class="row" method="GET" action="/compete">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
 <div class="column large-2">
  <label for="period"><strong>&nbsp;<br>Period:</strong></label>
   </div>
   <div class="column large-8">
   <select id="period" name="period">
   <option value="39">01. Oct 2018 - 31. Oct 2018 - Open</option><option    value="38">01. Sep 2018 - 30. Sep 2018 - Open</option><option value="37">01. Aug 2018 - 31. Aug 2018 - Open</option><option value="36">01. Jul 2018 - 31. Jul 2018 - Open</option><option value="35">01. Jun 2018 - 30. Jun 2018 - Open</option><option value="34">01. May 2018 - 31. May 2018 - Open</option><option value="33">01.
```

What I am doing wrong, please assist.

Comment: `//*[@id="period"]/option/contains(@value, 'Open')` In your `//*[@id="period"]/contains(@text, '')` you  can write any word instead of text - it does not find anything, it is true always

Comment: @splash58 Unfortunately, it does not work. Just tried and got endless list of: false, false, false ....

Comment: can you share link please ?

Comment: @MaheshKaria It is not public, sorry. Will add part of html in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print all the months which have **`Open`** as a part of title you can use the following code block :

```
Select months = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("period")));
List<WebElement> monthList = months.getOptions();
for(WebElement month:monthList)
    if(month.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Open"))
        System.out.println(month.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB Perfect!